# Subsonic 3: How do I generate predefined set of stored procedures?

Tags: subsonic3

I have a large database with 1000s of stored procedures.. But I need to use only some of them (say about 25 stored procs out of 1000). What should I change in T4 templates to limit the code generation to only those stored procedures that I need? Otherwise Subsonic 3 will generate all of them...

Thanks,
Zohrab.

Answer (score 0):

Here's What I did:

1. Added following into SQLServer.ttinclude

   // Customize the SP list here

   const string SP_SQL=@"SELECT* 
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
       WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' AND
       ROUTINE_NAME = 'My Stored Procedure Name' OR
           ROUTINE_NAME = 'My other Stored Procedure Name'
       ";
2. Replaced List GetSPs method in SQLServer.ttinclude with following:

   ```
   List<SP> GetSPs(){
   var result=new List<SP>();

   //[Z.B.]pull the stored procedures in a reader
   using(IDataReader rdr=GetReader(SP_SQL)){
       while(rdr.Read()){

           var sp=new SP();
           sp.Name = rdr["ROUTINE_NAME"].ToString();
           sp.CleanName=CleanUp(sp.Name);

           sp.Parameters=GetSPParams(sp.Name);
           result.Add(sp);        
       }
   }

   return result;
   ```

   }